# How to delete a Vector in an Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently trying to create my own snake game in JS and having a hard time finding a solution to a really easy problem. So I want to apologize in advance if i annoy someone.

I want the said Snake to have a tail that is not longer than the variable 'length'. If it is the last Vector (storing positions of the tail part) in the Array should be deleted - aka the oldest one. Here's the updated code:

```
////Snake Class//////
    function Snake() {
        var scl = 20;
        this.tail = [];
        this.length = 5;

        this.x = 0;
        this.y = cnv.height / 2;
        this.xspeed = 1;
        this.yspeed = 0;

        this.move = function (x, y) {
            this.xspeed =  x;
            this.yspeed =  y;
        }

        this.update = function () {
            this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
            this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;        

            this.tail.unshift(createVector(this.x, this.y));

            if(this.tail.length > this.length) {
                this.tail.pop();
            }
        }

        this.show = function (){
            for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
                rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
            }
        }
    }


//////////Main Class///////////

function setup() {
    cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    cnv.style('display','block');
    background(249,49,119);

    frameRate(10);
    s = new Snake();
}

function draw() {
    s.update();
    s.show();
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode == UP_ARROW) {
        console.log("UP");
        s.move(0, -1);
    }else if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW){
        s.move(0,1);
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW){
        s.move(-1, 0);
    }else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW){
        s.move(1, 0);
    }
}

/////Html///////

<html>
    <head>
        <script 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com
        /ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/
        libs/p5.js/0.7.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/
        libs/p5.js/0.7.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

   <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" type = "text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <script src = "Main.js"></script>
        <script src = "Snake.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>


///CSS///
html, body {
    background-color: #919191;

    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;

    /*Centers the Game horizontally*/
    justify-content: center;

    /*Centers the Game vertically*/
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: sounds like the [pop property of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is what you're looking for. Other methods for removing the first item ([unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)) and also removing one or more items from any given point in the array ([splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) might be good to know

Comment: Can you please share the HTML as well so we can fully test the code?

Comment: Yep, added the Html, Css and main class - it seems that i missed something out when removing the last object of the Array (or drawing it) - but i am not sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this.update(), you want to remove the first element in the array - but there are two normal mechanisms for this.

```
if (this.tail.length > this.length) {
    this.tail.pop();  // removes the oldest snake section.
}
```

However!

The two mechanisms I referred to are:

1. Redraw the world each time.
2. Redraw the updates to the snake. (i.e. erase the tail by drawing a blank there.)

You have to choose, one, I'm not sure what you are doing now.

To erase it, you would draw over the 0th element.  If you draw the whole world each time, then the removal from the array is good enough.  Since it will only draw what is in the array.

You have an update() and show() - many frameworks would call those functions update() and draw(), and the update() is usually responsible for the math/data manipulation (update the snake spots for instance), and draw() draws the world based on the data.   It seems like that is what you are going for.

The problem you will have is after you pop the 0th element - it won't exist when you get to draw/show().  So I recommend if you are going to keep this you would want to draw the whole world each time, otherwise, you would be forced to draw in the update function.